# java multithread server client communication

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been writing client-server application. I created multi-threaded server. I wonder how to do properly communication between server and client. There are two clients (2 game players) who have unique GUID number (threads are named the same). Player threads are working together.

Server has already received player GUID numbers in previous step. Server threads are working all the time.

I have a problem with a step - how to provide proper order of players. 
I tried simple example:

Server - is sending GUID (String):
- firstly - player1,
- secondly - player2.
Fragment :

```
public class ServerToPlayer implements Runnable //server creates this thread for each player
{
    private ObjectOutputStream output;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
            ...
            while(true)
            {
            output.writeObject(String.valueOf(localKey1)); //localKey1 - GUID number of Player1 
            output.writeObject(String.valueOf(localKey2)); //localKey2 - GUID number of Player2 
            break;
            }  
        }
}
```

Thread player class:

```
public class Player implements Runnable
{
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private static boolean startPlayer = true;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(String.valueOf(GUIDPlayer)); // GUIDPlayer
                                                                    // -
                                                                    // describes
                                                                    // player in
                                                                    // server

        // ...
        while (true)
        {
            String guidInput = (String) input.readObject(); // guid from server
            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals(guidInput))
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    startPlayer = true;
                    doMovement(); // proper player is doing sth
                    startPlayer = false;
                    notify();
                }
            } else if (!Thread.currentThread().getName().endsWith(guidInput))
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        wait();
                        if (!startPlayer)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The question is how to provide thread communication to receive in this example:
1. first iteration: class Player receives localKey1 from server (GUID of player1):
- player1 should be executing, and player2 should wait
2. second iteration: change executing player - class Player receives localKey2 from server (GUID of player2):
- player2 should be executing, and player1 should wait.
```

Using this code - player1 is executing, player2 is waiting and is not be woken up; so next step is wrong too. How to improve synchronization?

I also tried to do this in this way:

```
if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals(guidInput))
    {
        startPlayer = true;
        doMovement();                   
        startPlayer = false;        
    }
    else if(!Thread.currentThread().getName().endsWith(guidInput))
    {
        while(true)
        {       
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        if(!startPlayer)
          break;
        }
    }
```

But in this way boolean startPlayer is not changed in th

Answer (score 0):

Few points including:

```
while(true) {
   output.writeObject(String.valueOf(localKey1)); //localKey1 - GUID number of Player1 
   output.writeObject(String.valueOf(localKey2)); //localKey2 - GUID number of Player2 
   break;
}
```

`break` makes `while` loop absolutely pointless, without `break` the loop will never end and will send a lot of strings very fast.

Related to your problem with `startPlayer` variable I suggest you read about `volatile` keyword.

If you want the players to act sequentially than you will have to pass control from server to player when no other players are acting and then BACK from player to server when the player is done.